# Trouble parsing Facebook JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to pull wall posts from a Facebook page but I'm having issues. I had no problem parsing the JSON for a Twitter feed, so I can't see what problems I'm running into.

Here's my code, and **[here's the tutorial I used for help](http://liljosh.com/facebook-page-json-rss-feed/)**:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=96551536516";             

    function disguise_curl($url) { 
        $curl = curl_init(); 
        $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
        $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
        $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
        $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
        $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
        $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
        $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
        $header[] = "Pragma: ";

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla'); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, ''); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 

        $html = curl_exec($curl); 
        curl_close($curl);

        return $html;
    }

    $response = json_decode(disguise_curl($url));

    foreach($response->entries as $block){
        echo
            "<li class='clearfix'>
                <div class='streamPosterName'>{$block->author}</div>
                <div class='postContent'>{$block->title}</div>
            </li>";
    }
?>
```

When parsing JSON on other parts of my page, I use the following method for referencing JSON objects:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Apple&rpp=50";             
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $curlout = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response = json_decode($curlout, true);

    foreach($response["results"] as $block){
        echo
            "<li class='clearfix'>
                <img src='".$block["profile_image_url"]."' />
                <div class='streamPosterName'>".$block["from_user_name"]."</div>
                <div class='streamPosterUsername'>@".$block["from_user"]."</div>
                <div class='postContent'>".$block["text"]."</div>
            </li>";
    }
?>
```

The previous code correctly pulls in tweets. The Facebook parsing delivers the following error:

> **Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in /home/public_html/mkt/index.php on line 260**

Line 260 is shown above:

```
<div class='streamPosterName'>{$block->author}</div>
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you defined 'not working'

Comment: This just means that $block->author is of type Object and not String, thus not echoable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class='streamPosterName'>{$block->author}</div>
```

By default, json_decode() represents JSON objects as PHP stdClass objects. The error means `$block->author` is an object, yet you are using it as if it were a string.

Perhaps try `$block->author->name`?

Comment: Ahh dang, silly mistake. Didn't read all the way through that JSON object. Thanks!